# Is it advisable to use a tourniquet on a dog for a snake bite?

Tags: hiking, first-aid, dogs

I'm a bit curious about this since the day I read an infographic tip from a veterinarian.

The reason stated by her is that it helps to not enlarge the site of the snake bite. Is this correct?

Because I used to think that it's 100% not recommended.

Here's the infographic in case you want to see it.

[image]

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate. The existing snake bite post is not species specific. I did not read all the recommendations in the post but the last one about ticks is clearly wrong (or insufficiently clear) see sister site post [Tick removal, to twist or not twist?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/17598/13)

Comment: Hey Aire, welcome to The Great Outdoors! I agree to @JamesJenkins that your question should be answered by the linked question and answers. But don't feel discouraged to continue participating at our site, it's easy to overlook an existing question and create a duplicate! Make sure to check out our [tour](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/tour) to have a close look at how things work here and why we close duplicates. Welcome!

Comment: Welcome from me too Aire! On our type of site, we don't usually answer things in comments, unless perhaps they're very short, like this. The Petful site [What to do if your dog is bitten by a snake](https://www.petful.com/pet-health/what-to-do-if-your-dog-is-bitten-by-a-snake/), says not to use a tourniquet on your dog because restricting bloodflow may cause serious damage to other organs in its body. I hope that's helpful, in addition to what you read about people, in the other questions that have been suggested!

Comment: Please note that if you add pictures to a question, their relevant text parts should also be in the question *as text* (literally). That way search engines can find it. Your question text comes close ;-)